# How do I send data to a node script from a browser?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

On page load, I am running this javascript in a script tag:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "http://lvh.me:1337", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({hello:"goodbye"}));
```

Then the code for the node script is

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    });
    console.log(request);
    response.end("");
}).listen(1337);
```

But in the console.log, I don't see my {"hello":"goodbye"} object anywhere. How do I get access to this object?

Comment: It says it's undefined.

Comment: The `request` object is a stream, so I think you'll need to handle the `data` event.

Comment: How do I do this @MinusFour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`createServer` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) tell us that the callback you provide will be triggered by the `request` event. The [`request` event docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) tell us that `request` (the first argument) is an [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage). This does not have a `body` property, but it implements [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) and you can listen for the `'data'` event to gather the data:

```
// ES2015 (all of the below is supported in current NodeJS)
let body = '';
request.on('data', chunk => body += chunk);
request.on('end', () => console.log(JSON.parse(body)));
```

or

```
// ES5
var body = '';
request.on('data', function (chunk) {
   body += chunk;
});
request.on('end', function(){
  console.log(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

There are a lot of http server implementations out there that will abstract this process for you and give you a `request.body` to work with. [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) is a prime example and will even parse JSON for you.

Comment: You're totally right... the typical express `body-parser`...!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're definitely on to something. I'm still having trouble. Now I'm getting  `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. It goes away when I comment out `console.log(JSON.parse(body));`

Comment: @NickManning would appear that `body` does not have valid JSON. Try just `console.log(body)`

Comment: @ExplosionPills---doing that outputs `[object Object]`.

Comment: Nevermind, sorry. I forgot that I had taken out `JSON.stringify` in my html file while I was trying to figure it out. Thanks @ExplosionPills and TJ Crowder.